# PhaseOne iXM-100 IIQ to JPG

Tags: dji, camera

I was given some PhaseOne iXM-100 `.IIQ` photos and I need to convert them into `.jpg` format. The iXM-100 was used with a DJI drone, though I am unsure if it was the M300 or M600. Due to have thousands of them, I'd like the conversion to happen programmatically (Python). I've tried a couple different methods, but both have failed.

First Code Block; works, but the output image is static. Seems that when I change the [image mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397157/how-to-read-a-raw-image-using-pil), it changes the static color. Some modes work and some do not.

```
from PIL import Image
rawData = open("D:/Downloads/P0036906.IIQ", 'rb').read()
imgSize = (640,480)
img = Image.frombytes('RGB', imgSize, rawData)
img.save("D:/Downloads/P0036906.jpg")
```

Second Code Block; errors out. Seems that the library cannot read an `.iiq` format

```
import rawpy
import imageio

path = "D:/Downloads/P0036906.IIQ"

with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess()
    imageio.imwrite('D:/Downloads/P0036906.jpg', rgb)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iqq_jpg.py", line 23, in <module>
    rgb = raw.postprocess()
  File "rawpy\_rawpy.pyx", line 887, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.postprocess
  File "rawpy\_rawpy.pyx", line 790, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.dcraw_process
  File "rawpy\_rawpy.pyx", line 438, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.ensure_unpack
  File "rawpy\_rawpy.pyx", line 432, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.unpack
  File "rawpy\_rawpy.pyx", line 936, in rawpy._rawpy.RawPy.handle_error
rawpy._rawpy.LibRawIOError: b'Input/output error'
```

Any suggestions on how to convert IIQ to JPG?

Input:
[image]

Output RGB:
[image]

Output CMYK:
[image]

Comment: I can convert an IIQ image using anonymous2♦'s code, but the jpg appears to have a greenish color layer, I think because the white balance is missing. Any suggestions on how to get the image with the right colors?

Comment: I have not attempted to use anonymouse2 code yet. I don't have a ton of experience using JS. You can download a free version of Capture One's software and convert them to JPEG. Take a look at the second answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is IIQ is a proprietary raw format that PhaseOne built/uses. I was unable to find any python tools that could convert into jpeg. I did find a discussion on using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=543c3a150fff81e97e1d8c24c761ad06&topic=3071.15) with IIQ if anyone finds that helpful. I evntually found that I needed to download a free trial version of [Capture One](https://www.captureone.com/en/account/download-trial?intent=trial-pro) in order to convert.

Answer (score 3):

PhaseONE now provides [an SDK to decode IIQ files](https://developer.phaseone.com/sdk/) into TIFF files *only*. Once it is in TIFF format however it can be converted to JPEG. I have used this SDK to write a simply binary which performs a conversion from IIQ files to TIFF, after which bulk conversion from TIFF to JPEG is straightforward since both are now standard file formats.

Note that each IIQ file is a TIFF file where a *preview* image (640x480) is stored where imagery data normally lives. The actual image data from the sensor is stored as a binary string in the Exif `MakerNote` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's not python, but there is a person [on the libraw forum](https://www.libraw.org/node/2665) who shares C++ code to convert IIQ to tif. I haven't actually tested out their code, but from what I understand of your needs it should work. You can probably alter the code so that the output is jpg; alternatively you can re-convert afterwards to jpg.

Full attribution: this code was written and placed on libraw forums through [this Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PnbVb2J8jXkoGiOWqEa_n8A5X4-5zGTJ/view) by t.sawka on 29 June, 2021.  I'm including here in case the link breaks.

```
// IIQ2JPG.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <optional>
#include <libraw/libraw.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

using std::filesystem::path;
using std::optional;
using boost::algorithm::to_lower;

bool convert(const path& in, const path& out, optional<path> out_thumb = nullopt);


int main()
{
    path in_dir = R"(...)";
    path out_dir = R"(...)";

    using di = std::filesystem::directory_iterator;
    for (di it = di{ in_dir }; it != di{}; it++)
    {
        if (!it->is_regular_file())
        {
            continue;
        }
    
        auto p = it->path();
        if (!p.has_extension())
        {
            continue;
        }

        auto ext = p.extension().string();
        to_lower(ext);
        if (ext.find("iiq") == std::string::npos)
        {
            continue;
        }

        auto name = p.filename().replace_extension();
        auto op = out_dir / (name.string() + ".tif");
        auto otp = out_dir / (name.string() + "_thumb.pnm");

        cout << "in: " << p << "\n";
        cout << "out: " << op << "\n";
    }
    


    return 0;
}

bool convert(const path& in, const path& out, optional<path> out_thumb)
{
    LibRaw proc;
    if (proc.open_file(in.c_str()) != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
    {
        cerr << "open_file\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (out_thumb)
    {
        if (proc.unpack_thumb() != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
        {
            cerr << "unpack_thumb\n";
            return false;
        }

        if (proc.dcraw_thumb_writer(out_thumb->string().c_str()) != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
        {
            cerr << "dcraw_thumb_writer\n";
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (proc.unpack() != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
    {
        cerr << "unpack\n";
        return false;
    }

    if (proc.dcraw_process() != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
    {
        cerr << "dcraw_process\n";
        return false;
    }


    proc.output_params_ptr()->output_tiff = 1;
    if (proc.dcraw_ppm_tiff_writer(out.string().c_str()) != LIBRAW_SUCCESS)
    {
        cerr << "dcraw_ppm_tiff_writer\n";
        return false;
    }

    proc.recycle();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try out.